# NSTextField Subclass won't show via Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I created a Subclass of NSTextField.
If i use it via code there's no problems, everything is fine and the component works as intended.
If i use it via Interface Builder the component just won't show.

Here is my inits for the subclass:

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect{

self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];

if(self){

    [self setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    [self setBezeled:NO];
    [self setEditable:NO];
    [self setSelectable:NO];
    [self.cell setUsesSingleLineMode:YES];

}

return self;

}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{

self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

if(self){
    NSLog(@"initWithCoder");
    [self setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [self setBezeled:NO];
    [self setEditable:NO];
    [self setSelectable:NO];
    [self.cell setUsesSingleLineMode:YES];
}

return self;


}
```

For instance, if i create two components , one by code and one by Interface builder i can see only the first component, with blueBackground.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is "initWithCoder" logged? How did you add the text field in IB? Did you set a value?

Comment: InitWithCoder is logged.
I add a customView, i change  the Class in the Identity inspector and then i add the referencing outlet to a property of the same Class. 
I espect to see a red frame at least. But no. I don't see nothing.

Comment: Add a `NSTextField` and change the class.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! Try to do an answer post i think that's gonna be useful for anyone else!

Answer (score 1):

When adding a subclass of an Appkit class in IB, add the nearest superclass and change the class in the Identity Inspector. So if you created a subclass of `NSTextField`, add a `NSTextField` and change the class.